# Creating an interactive Pie Chart where values change over time

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, charts, pie-chart

I've been trying to find a code example to work off for ages but can't find anything similar.

What I'm trying to create is a pie chart with a horizontal scroll bar below it which the user can scrub across, changing the year. The values in the pie chart above will change accordingly. Preferable animating between those values.

The worse case scenario is having one long timeline animation which the user will scrub through using the bar at the bottom. I still have the problem though of creating the piechart shapes. It would be much simpler as a bar chart as it would just be the heights that need changing but that's not an option.

This piece of code I found creates a pie chart but I don't think I can change the values in different frames of the timeline. Maybe I'm doing that wrong but its throwing up an error. I can't find any examples that are truly interactive.

http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/creating-charts-using-as3-part-11.html

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can achieve what I'm after?

PS. Also, I will be converting the flash project to html5 when I publish it

Thanks

Comment: look at D3.js - can do all of that and more - though you may  have to build it yourself. really worth the time to learn it.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Timeline sucks, you'd better do interactive single-frame application with a scroller as a control item, and then you do your animations all by yourself. (You can also skip animating changes until you'll be able to launch core functionality.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've had a brief look at that, and I'm sure it will be something to learn in the future, however at this moment I would like to use flash, as there are some parts I am very familiar with and would like to exploit that

Comment: Sorry I just saw the latest comments. I've got a pie chart being created now, and I'm using variables for the size. I am currently trying to figure out how I can change that variable in the main project, depending on the frame I'm on, that changes the variable in the attached actionscript code

Answer (score 0):

As @vesper says, ditch the timeline as it will only lead to pain.

The key is to define your data in a multidimensional `array` and then use the scroller to update an index correlating to the elements in your `array`. You can then redraw the chart using the data from the corresponding element.

Something like the following (untested) should provide you a solid starting point. Note that I've come up with a hypothetical scroller so you'll need to update those parts of the code to match the properties and events of the one you use. Also note that you could simplify matters initially by having the chart redraw based on the click of a series of buttons, one for each element in your multidimensional `array`.

```
// Set the default (or starting) index
var currentIndex = 0;

// Define your data as a multidimensional array
var myData:Array = [
    [{val:51,color:0x00CCFF,lab:"Internet Explorer"}, ...],
    [{val:41,color:0x00CCFF,lab:"Internet Explorer"}, ...],
    [{val:31,color:0x00CCFF,lab:"Internet Explorer"}, ...]
];

// Fictional scroller which I have imagined
var scroller:Scroller = new Scroller();
scroller.addEventListener('scrolled', scrollHandler);

// Handler for fictional scroller which I have imagined
function scrollHandler(event)
{
    // Get a number between 0 and the length of the data array
    var index = Math.floor((scroller.scrollX / scroller.scrollWidth) * (myData.length - 1));

    // Only react if the index has changed
    if (index != currentIndex)
    {
        currentIndex = index;
        draw(currentIndex);
    }
}

function draw(index) 
{
    // Draw the chart using data from the supplied index
    drawChart(200, 150, 100, myData[index]);
}

// Do the initial draw
draw(currentIndex);

// Your pie chart code ....
```